# updating angular-cli throws error

Tags: node.js, angular, webpack, angular-cli

```
ABC$ sudo npm install -g angular-cli@latest
npm WARN deprecated angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3: angular-cli has been 
renamed to @angular/cli. Please update your dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 
3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
/usr/local/bin/ng -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng

> fsevents@1.1.3 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-
cli/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(undefined): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.1.3/fse-v1.1.3-node-v51-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.1.3 and node@7.8.0 (node-v51 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp ERR! clean error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "clean"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v7.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js clean' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:899:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v7.8.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.39
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js clean' (1)

> node-sass@4.6.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass
>   node scripts/install.js

```
Unable to save binary /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/darwin-x64-51 : { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:895:18)
at sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
at Function.sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
at checkAndDownloadBinary (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:111:11)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:154:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'mkdir',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/vendor' }

> node-sass@4.6.1 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass
>   node scripts/build.js

```
Building: /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.6.2
gyp info using node@7.8.0 | darwin | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:114:15)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:114:15)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at
```

getNotFoundError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/which/which.js:13:12)\n    at F (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/which/which.js:68:19)\n    at E (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/which/which.js:80:29)\n    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/which/which.js:89:16\n    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/isexe/index.js:42:5\n    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/isexe/mode.js:8:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:114:15)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python /usr/bin/python
gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version());"` returned: "2.7.10\n"
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 7.8.0
gyp verb command install [ '7.8.0' ]
gyp verb install input version string "7.8.0"
gyp verb install installing version: 7.8.0
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 7.8.0
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v7.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.10 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/angular-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 install: `node install`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.6.1 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.6.1 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ABC/.npm/_logs/2017-11-12T09_23_09_328Z-debug.log

Comment: Did you uninstall it before installing?

Comment: Yes. as I thought it would be ideal way to do.

Comment: Here's your error `npm WARN deprecated angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3: angular-cli has been renamed to @angular/cli.`

Comment: *WARN deprecated angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3: angular-cli has been 
renamed to @angular/cli*: you're using an abandoned beta version.  Forget about angular-cli, and use the maintained project:@angular/cli. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Answer (score 0):

You're installing the wrong version of the cli.

> npm WARN deprecated angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3: angular-cli has been 
>   renamed to @angular/cli.

You should do this instead:

```
npm uninstall -global angular-cli @angular/cli
npm install -global @angular/cli
```

Comment: facing this error while uninstalling from global. - npm ERR! path /usr/local/bin/ng
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete /usr/local/bin/ng: ../lib/node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng symlink target is not controlled by npm /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
npm ERR! File exists: /usr/local/bin/ng
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

Comment: @Samir Well, move it away, and try again.